# how to put a splash screen on android apps?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

i want to make my app look nice. i want to add a splash screen on starting up.
after the splash screen (3-5 sec) the app should start Activitygrade678.

here's the xml of splash screen

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageView
       android:src="@drawable/final2"
       android:id="@+id/splash"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the splash.java

```
    import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class splash extends Activity {

        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

 }
   }
```

after the splash i want it to move to the app

```
Intent intent = new Intent (splash.this,Actvitygrade678.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: using a splash screen is a bad design practice..You should try avoiding it

Comment: Using a splash screen is not a bad design practice per-se. What is a bad practice is showing a splash screen for no reason other than to show a logo (I've even seen people doing a Thread.sleep(3000) to let the splash screen 3 seconds… It is advisable to try to get the user to your content as soon as possible without a SplashScreen. Sometimes it's needed to show branding while an operation takes place.

Comment: I just want to learn something new

Answer (score 2):

First create your desired layout and than in your main starting activity run one thread which shows splash screen layout for given time and then Launch MainActivity 
E[enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    private final int DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
            super.onCreate(saved);
            setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                    Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    Splash.this.finish();
                }
            }, DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain this or link some video. There is no use if I just copy paste. I want to understand this thing.